# Serialize list of Name Value pairs with excluding the Key and Value parts

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have the class below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class Incident
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("components")]
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Components { get; set; }

        public Incident()
        {
            Components = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        }
    }
}
```

If I have an object where I add a single NameValuePair with a key of ddd and value of dssds...

When converting this to Json

I currently get

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "components": [{ "Key": "ddd", "Value": "dssds" }]
}
```

I need

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "components": {
       "ddd": "dssds"
   }
}
```

I serialize wih

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incident);
```

How can I do this?  Im assuming I need some kind of converter?

One suggestion is

```
var test = new { name = incident.Name, components = incident.Components.Select(i => i.Value) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

This generates

```
{
  "name":"test",
  "components":["dssds"]
}
```

Which does not match my required json above

Paul

Comment: Ive updated the question.  I cant have a list of values because I need a name and value as shown above

Comment: how about the expected result if ``components`` contains more than one element?

Comment: It will only have 1 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you want, `Components` needs to be a `Dictionary<string, string>` rather than a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.  So the simplest solution is to change your class to that effect:

```
public class Incident
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("components")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Components { get; set; }

    public Incident()
    {
        Components = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mx4Z8U

Of course, the drawback to this solution is that you now have to update all the code which uses `Incident` to work with a `Dictionary` rather than a `List`.  Depending on how many dependencies there are, you may or may not want to do that.

So, the second simplest solution is to create a surrogate `Dictionary<string, string>` property in the class which uses the `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as its source of data.  It can be private if you like.  Move the `[JsonProperty("components")]` attribute to the new `Dictionary` and mark the `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` with `[JsonIgnore]` instead.  So you would have this:

```
public class Incident
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Components { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("components")]
    private Dictionary<string, string> ComponentDictionary
    {
        get { return Components != null ? new Dictionary<string, string>(Components) : null; }
    }

    public Incident()
    {
        Components = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Po22Yt

Comment: This is a new project so I don’t have hardly any dependencies